# Get Ansible on windows to print version

Tags: windows, ansible, windows-10

I am trying to get an Ansible task to print the version used while running on `Windows 10`.

I am currently trying something like this:

```
---

# Source: https://serverfault.com/a/695798
- name: Get version
  win_shell: ansible --version
  register: ansibleVersion

# How I chose to expose the version collected
- name: Display version
  win_msg:
    msg: "Ansible Version: {{ ansibleVersion.stdout }}"
    display_seconds: 30
```

However, I am getting this output:

```
"stderr": "ansible : The term 'ansible' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. \r\nCheck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.\r\n
```

Full disclosure, I am new to Ansible.  I have tried `win_command`, `win_shell`, and am not really sure what all to try next.

Comment: What I can see is that ansible was not recognized/found on the host on which the ansible script was executed. If the ansible executable is present in some directory you can use the `chdir` argument with `win_shell` module.

Comment: Where would the ansible `.exe` script be located normally?

Comment: As far as I know there is no Ansible `.exe` for Windows. Have you installed Ansible on WSL (as described here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/windows_faq.html#can-ansible-run-on-windows)?

Comment: Ansible is running on your controller, there is no counterpart on your node, just scripts runs by python, there, that is why [Ansible is said to be agentless](https://www.ansible.com/hubfs/pdfs/Benefits-of-Agentless-WhitePaper.pdf)

Comment: Also read: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_faq.html#can-ansible-run-on-windows

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer Have you tried the solution, does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it turns out my problem was being too abstracted from Ansible in a company.  I would write Ansible tasks, and then initiate deploys using a web interface `TeamCity`.  I for some reason thought Ansible was being run on my local Windows machine as the user `ansible`.  However, I have now learned that actually Ansible is run from Linux VM, and configures the machine remotely.

Comment: @ShubhamVaishnav yes your answer has helped me realize that Ansible was being run from a Linux machine.  That helped me realize what was actually happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to all those who answered and commented.  The articles were very informative, and I learned a much more about Ansible.  The answers put me on the scent of the actual task I made.

To restate my comment on the original question, I had a misunderstanding.  Because on my Windows machine I had to add a user `ansible`, I thought it was being run locally somehow.  However, it turns out, Ansible deploys are being run from a Linux VM.

Once I had this misunderstanding cleared up, I realized I needed to use `delegate_to: 127.0.0.1` in my Ansible task.  Here is my `Check Ansible version` task:

```yaml
---

# SEE: https://serverfault.com/a/695798/514234
- name: Check Ansible version
  command: ansible --version
  register: ansibleVersion
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

- name: Print version
  debug:
    msg: "Ansible Version: {{ ansibleVersion.stdout }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The Windows machines can be provisioned using ansible but not installed on Windows.

You can **configure the Windows machine from a Linux machine** as the controller host.
And you can run the ansible-playbook from this controller host which will run on the windows machine.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Get Windows version
      win_shell: "systeminfo /fo csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | select OS*, System*, Hotfix* | Format-List"
      register: windows_version

    - name: Print Windows host information
      debug:
        msg: "{{ windows_version }}"
```

Save this as main.yml

Add the Windows host IP in `hosts` file

```
[win]
172.16.*.*

[win:vars]
ansible_user=user
ansible_password=password
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

Run the playbook using the following command

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml
```

If you want ansible on Windows, then there are other installation methods to run it on Windows.

Also mentioned in the comments.
I have attached some links to setup ansible on Windows 10 subsytem for Linux,

[Ansible - Windows Frequently asked questions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/windows_faq.html#can-ansible-run-on-windows)

[Using Ansible through Windows 10's Subsystem for Linux](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/using-ansible-through-windows-10s-subsystem-linux)

Hope it solves your issue.